# Django Rest Framework: issue with request.data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to use Django rest framework for my server implementation.  I get the following error when I attempt to POST.

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Here is the code for the view.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from whiteboards.models import Whiteboard, Path, Point
from whiteboards.serializers import WhiteboardSerializer

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def whiteboard_list(request):
   """
   List all whiteboards, or create a new whiteboard.
   """


   if request.method == 'GET':
       print('GET')
       whiteboards = Whiteboard.objects.all()
       serializer = WhiteboardSerializer(whiteboards, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)

   elif request.method == 'POST':
       print('POST')
       d = request.data
       print('data broke')
       serializer = WhiteboardSerializer(data=d)
       print("created serializer")
       if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
           print("It's valid")
           return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **version 3** (latest) - **request.DATA** has been replaced with **[request.dat](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data)a**:

```
user = dict(
                    full_name=request.data['full_name'],
                    password=request.data['password'],
                    email=request.data['email']                
                )
```

---

In version 2 - it was [request.DATA](http://tomchristie.github.io/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/requests#data):

```
user = dict(
                full_name=request.DATA['full_name'],
                password=request.DATA['password'],
                email=request.DATA['email']          
            )
```

Answer (score 3):

try `request.DATA` instead of `request.data`

Comment: That worked.  Thank you!  I guess the Django rest framework tutorial was wrong.

Comment: I think they are updating the documentation for the new upcoming 3.0 version. They swapped request.DATA to request.data in the new version. You may be using 2.3.4 or 2.4.4 where request.DATA is the way to go. You can check the change here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#request-objects